# The service "twig" has a dependency on a non-existent service "sonata.classification.manager.tag"

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony-sonata

I am upgrading an site from Symfony 2.2 to 2.3.

I am using sonata an other bundles, 2.2 version was fine.

I stuck with this message.

> [Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException]
>     The service "twig" has a dependency on a non-existent service "sonata.classification.manager.tag".

Exception:

> Exception trace:
>    () at /home/cslucano/Projects/oDesk/tr/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Compiler/CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass.php:59
>    Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass->processReferences() at /home/cslucano/Projects/oDesk/tr/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Compiler/CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass.php:43
>    Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass->processDefinition() at /home/cslucano/Projects/oDesk/tr/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Compiler/CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass.php:54
>    Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass->processReferences() at /home/cslucano/Projects/oDesk/tr/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Compiler/CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass.php:52
>    Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass->processReferences() at /home/cslucano/Projects/oDesk/tr/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Compiler/CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass.php:52
>    Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass->processReferences() at /home/cslucano/Projects/oDesk/tr/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Compiler/CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass.php:44
>    Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass->processDefinition() at /home/cslucano/Projects/oDesk/tr/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Compiler/CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass.php:37
>    Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass->process() at /home/cslucano/Projects/oDesk/tr/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Compiler/Compiler.php:119
>    Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\Compiler->compile() at /home/cslucano/Projects/oDesk/tr/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php:629
>    Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->compile() at /home/cslucano/Projects/oDesk/tr/app/bootstrap.php.cache:2407
>    Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->initializeContainer() at /home/cslucano/Projects/oDesk/tr/app/bootstrap.php.cache:2187
>    Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->boot() at /home/cslucano/Projects/oDesk/tr/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Console/Application.php:70
>    Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application->doRun() at /home/cslucano/Projects/oDesk/tr/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:121
>    Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at /home/cslucano/Projects/oDesk/tr/app/console:22

Comment: include the exception trace please ... cleared your cache? :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I added the

```
new Sonata\ClassificationBundle\SonataClassificationBundle(),
```

in `app/AppKernel.php` and then it worked.